# Исполнение python кода на клиенте в браузере

Tags: python, python-3.x, веб-программирование, django, frontend

Доброго времени суток.

**Предисловие**

При написании программы в виде вэб-сервиса хочется, чтобы была возможность часть операций исполнять на Клиенте в виде python скриптов.

Пользователь входит на сайт, включает приложение. При нажимании в браузере Кнопка1 исполняется python скрипт, а на Кнопка2(допустим) отправлялись данные на сервер.

Хочу логику приложения на клиенте вынести в python, а логику интерфейса в JS.

Никакого плохо предлога, т.е вариант спросить пользователя возможен.

Не предусматривается установка на Клиент этих скриптов(тобишь зашел, полул скрипты вместе с Html страницей и по выходу они исчезли). Либо через расширение Google Chrome.

P.S. Приложение на Django сидит, но переход на другое возможен.

**Вопрос:**

Какие решения есть по этому поводу и есть ли вообще?

Comment: По идее, такое можно будет делать, когда во всех браузерах будет поддержка wasm, но оно пока ещё вообще на стадии разработки. Так что на данный момент - никак. А почему вы не хотите реализовать эту логику тоже на js?

Comment: @Александр дело в том, что это функционал подразумевается как Open Source. А люди, которые буду с этим работать, кроме python в основном ничего не знают. Хм, а если все же установить приложение на комп и при открытие ссылки часть запросов будут транслироваться на комп?

Comment: @Александр и да, часть функционала уже есть на Python(библиотеки) + я JS не очень люблю.

Comment: @Александр хм, возникла идея. Большинство пользователей все же на Google Chrome. А если вместе с WASM, скомпилированного из Rust, закину python скрипты и библиотеки, не обходимые для запуска python кода... Какие подводные камни вы видите?

Comment: Я сам с wasm пока не работал, и представления о нём имею только теоретически. Но лично я бы вообще не стал использовать его для боевого проекта на данном этапе его развития.

Comment: Но вообще, складывается впечатление, что у вас что-то не так с самим подходом... Этот функционал точно нельзя выполнять на серверной стороне?

Comment: @Александр можно, но абсолютно не нужно. Это приложение, которое запускается в браузере. Аутентификация только в браузере и сохранение данных. А работа вся ведеся на клиенте. Да, можно реализовать это на сервере, но тогда нужно больше мощностей на сервак.

Comment: если *"люди, которые буду с этим работать, кроме python в основном ничего не знают"*  то какую функциональность браузер предоставляет? Какую функциональность на Питоне люди будут писать? Рассмотрите варианты, в которых только один язык используется.

Comment: @jfs функциональность визуальную. Тобишь человек пишет функциональность, которая ему нужна(именно сам процесс), делает pull request. Я его одобряю, добавляю в общую мешанину и пишу к нему UI

Comment: обновите вопрос и подробнее опишите задачу (пишите вещи, которые вам очевидными кажутся, иначе в объяснении много белых пятен, которые не ясно как заполнить). Сейчас я вообще не понимаю, зачем что-то на сайт добавлять кроме инструкции и ссылки на github репозиторий

Comment: @jfs Я это не писал, ибо это к вопросу не относится. Но опишу проблему подробнее на примере.

Comment: Rusthon, python-js, и прочие трансляторы в js код будут работать, но будут тормозить чаще всего. Если знаете только питон, возможно приложение на gtk, qt - подойдет лучше под вашу задачу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - подключить что-то типа [Sculpt](https://skulpt.org/) - позволяет запускать Python скрипты в браузере. Для этого достаточно добавить перед `</head>` следующее:

```
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/js/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/js/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Альтернатив `Skulpt` есть несколько, например [Brython](https://brython.info/).

[Здесь](https://yasoob.me/2019/05/22/running-python-in-the-browser/) статья со сравнением 6 систем, включая `Skulpt` и `Brython`.